# I have this ranking system where I want to add 0.5 when 2 contestants matches score. And if they match, the next number will skip one

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

```
public function getRanking($criteria_id, $contestant_id){
    $contestants = $this->findBy('event_id', $this->find($contestant_id)->event_id);

    $contestant_score = $this->getScore($criteria_id, $contestant_id);

    $ranking = 1;

    foreach($contestants as $c){
        if($c->id != $contestant_id){
            if($this->getScore($criteria_id, $c->id) > $contestant_score){
                if($ranking === $ranking) {
                    $ranking = $ranking - 0.5;
                }else{
                    $ranking++;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return $ranking;
}
```

1. Contestant 1 score 30 rank 1.5
2. Contestant 2 score 30 rank 1.5
3. Contestant 3 score 29 rank 3

Comment: You can do it at database level if you want: [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/ZUa9Rurn).